# Expressive power of Liquid Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, logic, liquid-haskell

Following up from my recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58806748/how-to-write-a-log2-function-in-liquid-haskell), I have been pondering over the following:

We can create some new amazing types in LH, particularly, express some non-trivial subsets of Integers. For example:

```hs
{-@ type Nat = {v:Int | v>=0 } @-}
{-@ type grtN N = {v:Int | v>N } @-}
{-@ type Even = {v:Int | v mod 2 == 0 } @-}
```

But now what other non-trivial subsets can I express in LH?

Can I create a type in LH which consists of only powers of 2? Which is what my last question was about and it seems like the answer is negative.

So a natural question which arises is what kind of subsets (of Integers) can I express?
Is there a nice characterization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that LH will *let* you write arbitrary arithmetic constraints. But only the theory of linear integer arithmetic is decidable (via presburger arithmetic) by the backend solver, so as soon as you start writing non-linear expressions you lose any guarantee that the solver will actually verify your code. Additionally, SMT solvers only support first-order logic, so you can't quantify over relations.